# Authorize create action based on the parent_id of the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have two models other than `User` model. `Hotel` and `Room`.

Here is the scenario:

```
hotel :has_many => :rooms
```

A User can create rooms if the associated hotel is assigned to the user. How can I implement authorization for the `create room` action in `ability`, as `hotel_id` is unknown till the room is going to be saved?

I can implement a `can?` method in `create action` under the `rooms controller` , but I am expecting to have it in `ability`. This problem should be resolved in `nested_resources` pattern but somehow I have to create rooms in a separate controller (not nested).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nested_resources` facility as outlined here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources **but** only set this for the specific create action of the separate controller using the specific action authorising methods outlined here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

**Edit - Updated with example for ability.rb as requested in comments:**

```
can :create, Room, :hotel => { :user_id => user.id }
```

Comment: yes!, As I mentioned in the post, using nested resources we can achieve that. As I have to use separate controller I used the second approach. That is I've put a authorization check on controller. I was expecting something to be manageable through the ability module. I guess there is no way for that

Comment: I've updated with the standard way of doing such abilities in the Ability.rb file